# When a method returns a value from an if else statement what should be contained in the else statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods

Just a beginner here, I have a console app that calculates the charge payable for a car park that's working fine, at least until you put in a value that's a positive number.

We've just started using multiple methods and my problem is that the method I'm passing the 'hours' value to use an If else statement to get the charge value but as the method passes back a double I'm a little confused as to what would be best practice for the else.

Ideally I'd want to be able to enter an invalid value (a negative integer) for 'hours' and the program would return an error message and bounce back to the start of the program again.

To get that effect now I'm setting the return on the else to change the value passed back to 0 and then using an if statement in the main method to deal with the situation where 'hours' = 0. Then I'm using a goto to do it right now but I'm not sure that's best practice. If it is, great, but if there's a better way I'd prefer not to be relying on a something that's messier.

Cheers for any and all help.

```
    class Program
{        

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double charge = 0;
        double hours = 0;
        string reg;

        start:

        while (hours != -999)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter hours : ");
            hours = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            charge = CalcCharge(hours);     

            if (charge == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("Invalid hour value. Please try again.\n");
                goto start;
            }

            Console.Write("\nEnter reg : ");
            reg = Console.ReadLine();

            if (reg == "Sligo")
                charge = charge - ((charge / 100) * 10);

            if (charge > 100)
                charge = 100;

            Console.Write("\nThe charge is ${0:f2}.", charge);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    static double CalcCharge(double hours)
    {
        double result;

        if (hours > 0 && hours < 7)
        {
            result = hours * 2;
            return result;
        }

        if (hours >= 7 && hours <= 10)
        {
            result = hours * 3;
            return result;

        }

        if (hours >= 11 && hours <= 15)
        {
            result = hours * 4;
            return result;

        }

        if (hours > 15)
        {
            result = hours * 3;
            return result;

        }

        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not use an `else` but instead throw an exception. An `ArgumentException` is probably correct to use here. Catch the exception instead of checking the return value:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //your code
    try
    {
        charge = CalcCharge(hours); 
    }
    catch(ArgumentException)
    {
        Console.Write("Invalid hour value. Please try again.\n");
        continue;
    }

...

static double CalcCharge(double hours)
{
    //Your code
    throw new ArgumentException("hours");
}
```

Also, avoid using `goto` as it's bad practice and can lead to very messy, spaghetti gross code. If you look at the example I use a `continue`, which basically says "go back to the start of the loop".

Answer (score 0):

I would probably change your function to this:

```
static double CalcCharge(double hours)
{
    double result = 0;

    if (hours > 0 && hours < 7)
    {
        result = hours * 2;        
    }
    else if ((hours >= 7 && hours <= 10) || hours > 15)
    {
        result = hours * 3;
    }
    else if (hours >= 11 && hours <= 15)
    {
        result = hours * 4;
    }
    else
    {
         throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("there was a problem!");
    }
    return result;

}
```

This is a little more concise and it lets you catch the exception in the parent function if something goes wrong.

Comment: 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in Sem2Assign1ExampleREAL.exe' when I try to use try/catch, the program just hangs when I enter a negative value for hours and spits out the above.

The throw new is exactly as you suggested but the try/catch is..

  try
                {
                    charge = CalcCharge(hours);
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    Console.Write("Invalid hour value. Please try again");
                    continue;
                }

Comment: If it's running for hours then the condition: `hours != -999` is never being met.  Is your message in the `catch` being printed out?